# How to bring the details row immediate next to the edit clicked row in angular8 using bootstrap

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

i need the details to be shown immediate next to the row on which i had clicked edit button.But here it is coming after all the data displayed in that table. But i need that to be immediate next based on data i fetch for.

HTML:

```
   <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let eo of eoList">
                <td (click)="editEo(eo)"><a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" href="#rowEO1">Edit</a></td>
                <td *ngFor="let field of eoListDetails" class="{{field.class}}">
                    {{eo[field.param]}}
                </td>
                <td><button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-table" title="Request Update"><i
                            class="far fa-paper-plane"></i></button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-table" title="View Dec Page"><i
                            class="fas fa-eye"></i></button></td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="6" class="hidden-row">
                    <div class="accordion-wrapper pt-3 px-3 collapse" id="rowEO1">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="">Legal Liability Limit - Each Loss <span
                                            class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                    <p class="form-control-plaintext font-weight-bold">$200.00</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="">Legal Liability Limit - Aggregate <span
                                            class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                    <p class="form-control-plaintext font-weight-bold">$200.00</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="">Deductible - Each Loss <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                    <p class="form-control-plaintext font-weight-bold">$200.00</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="">Deductible - Aggregate <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                    <p class="form-control-plaintext font-weight-bold">$200.00</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="">Update Requested</label>
                                    <p class="form-control-plaintext font-weight-bold">11/07/2019</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="">Update Received</label>
                                    <p class="form-control-plaintext font-weight-bold">11/07/2019</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col d-flex justify-content-end align-items-end">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <button class="btn btn-primary min-w100">Edit</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vnf785?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: @Shb, any idea about it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60146919/how-to-edit-or-add-one-row-at-a-time-using-reactive-forms-in-angular8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a unique id in each row like this :

```
public eoList = [{"id":'1',"eocarrier":'AIG Insurance','policynumber':'1234','effectivedate':'12/05/2019','expirationdate':'12/05/2019'},
  {"id":'2',"eocarrier":'HISCOX Insurance','policynumber':'2345','effectivedate':'18/05/2019','expirationdate':'12/05/2019'},
  {"id":'3',"eocarrier":'AIG Insurance','policynumber':'8765','effectivedate':'19/05/2019','expirationdate':'12/05/2019'},
  {"id":'4',"eocarrier":'HISCOX Insurance','policynumber':'2345','effectivedate':'12/11/2019','expirationdate':'12/05/2019'}]
```

Then you can wrap your `<tr>` inside `<ng-container></ng-container>` and set accordion `id` as `row_{{eo.id}}`

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ehgrhz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: I will try this and let you know, I hope id would be fine

Comment: can we have one row open at a time on click of edit?

Comment: any idea about this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60146919/how-to-edit-or-add-one-row-at-a-time-using-reactive-forms-in-angular8