# How to edit or add one row at a time using reactive forms in angular8

Tags: angular, forms, angular-reactive-forms, reactive

I have a list of data, when i click on rows, all the rows are editable and when i click on edit button of the expanded row, all the rows will have the same value as in the first row, but that shouldnt happen.One row can be editable at a table, when clicked on edit button in the expanded row, add new should also not be done. But i am going wrong somewhere, can anyone help me.

DEMO:

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zpuy3x?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

TS:

```
eoEdit(eo) {
    console.log(eo)
    this.eoDetailsList = eo
   this.hideEoView = false;
   this.initEoForm()
  }
```

HTML:

```
 <table class="table table-hover accordion-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th scope="col" *ngFor="let field of eoListDetails" (click)="sortEoList(field.param)">
                    {{field.displayName}}
                    <i class="{{field.icon}}" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </th>
                <th scope="col" class="width75"></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <ng-container *ngFor="let eo of eoList">
                <tr>
                    <td (click)="editEo(eo)"><a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" href="#row_{{eo.eoid}}"><i
                                class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i></a></td>
                    <td *ngFor="let field of eoListDetails" class="{{field.class}}">
                        {{eo[field.param]}}
                    </td>
                    <td><button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-table" title="Request Update"><i
                                class="far fa-paper-plane"></i></button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-table" title="View Dec Page"><i
                                class="fas fa-eye"></i></button></td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="6" class="hidden-row">
                        <div class="accordion-wrapper pt-3 px-3 collapse" id="row_{{eo.eoid}}">
                            <div class="row" *ngIf="hideEoView">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="">Legal Liability Limit - Each Loss <span
                                                class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                        <p class="form-control-plaintext font-weight-bold">{{eo.legalLiabilityLoss}}</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="">Legal Liability Limit - Aggregate <span
                                                class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                        <p class="form-control-plaintext font-weight-bold">{{eo.legalLiabilityAggregate}}</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="">Deductible - Each Loss <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                        <p class="form-control-plaintext font-weight-bold">{{eo.deductibleLoss}}</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="">Deductible - Aggregate <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                        <p class="form-control-plaintext font-weight-bold">{{eo.deductibleAggregate}}</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row" *ngIf="hideEoView">
                                <div class="col-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="">Update Requested</label>
                                        <p class="form-control-plaintext font-weight-bold">{{eo.effectivedate}}</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="">Update Received</label>
                                        <p class="form-control-plaintext font-weight-bold">{{eo.updateReceived}}{{eo.updateReceivedHours}}</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div *ngIf="!hideEoView">
                            <form *ngIf="eoInfoForm && eoDetailsList" [formGroup]="eoInfoForm">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="">E&amp;O Carrier <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="E&amp;O Carrier" formControlName="eoCarrier">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="">Policy Number <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Policy Number" formControlName="policyNumber">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="">Effective Date <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control onlyDate" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY"
                                                formControlName="effectiveDate">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="">Expiration Date <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control onlyDate" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY"
                                                formControlName="expirationDate">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="">Legal Liability Limit - Each Loss <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Legal Liability Limit - Each Loss"
                                                formControlName="legalLiabilityLimitEachLoss">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="">Legal Liability Limit - Aggregate <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Legal Liability Limit - Aggregate"
                                                formControlName="legalLiabilityLimitAggregate">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="">Deductible - Each Loss <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Deductible - Each Loss"
                                                formControlName="deductibleEachLoss">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="">Deductible - Aggregate <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Deductible - Aggregate"
                                                formControlName="deductibleAggregate">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="">Update Requested</label>
                                            <p class="form-control-plaintext font-weight-bold">12/19/19 4:19 PM jcargile</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-6">
                                        <div class="form-group" formGroupName="updateReceived">
                                            <label for="">Update Received</label>
                                            <div class="input-group">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control onlyDate" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY"
                                                    formControlName="date">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control onlyTime" placeholder="hh:mm AM/PM"
                                                    formControlName="time">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col d-flex justify-content-end align-items-end">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary min-w100" (click)="eoDetailsList ? saveDetails() : eoEdit(eo)">{{eoDetailsList ? 'Save' : 'Edit'}}</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>

                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ng-container>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: You mean, you want to edit one child row at a time ?

Comment: Yes correct, and the values are also binding to everything which i had clicked first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See working [demo](https://angular-ekwjd7.stackblitz.io)

You need to add a flag for each row, and set it to true when the row is editable, currently you are using a common variable eoDetailsList to decide row is editable or not, and that affects all rows.

I have added these two flags. Yes you need to add manually

[image]

Comment: Any example for this??

Comment: See I have forked your demo to do this:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7v9wqm, it is not fully working but it will give you idea how use flag.

Comment: yes i got, so you mean to the edit data itself i need to set flag and which is true to that i need to bind?

Comment: Yes, as you want to maintain edit/save mode for each row, you need those details in  each row.

Comment: Incase if you get time, have a look at it, i will also check meanwhile and also check for your answer posted and give you upvote

Comment: but from the api hit, i wont be getting those flags, i need to manually add it?

Comment: Yes, see in answer. I have added isSave, and hideEoView in forked stackblitz

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207534/discussion-between-bhrungarajni-and-milan-raval).

Answer (score 0):

You are using common controller `eoDetailsList` to ensure it is editable or not. That controller is affecting of the related functions in your project. The easiest way is controller for each task, like `editable: true` or `editable: false`. It will not affect whole projects rather than let you allow to edit the particular row.

Comment: I have done so far and strcuk at half place, could you please help me out where i am strcuk, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60231853/how-to-throw-validation-message-when-the-form-is-dirty-and-trying-to-click-on-ot